# Mouse move code snippet doesnt work with Kinect sdk2.0

Tags: c#, kinect

Although am getting the values of cursorX, cursorY there is no movement of my mouse cursor. Am I missing anything?

```
Joint hand = helper.handRight;

CameraSpacePoint position = hand.Position;

DepthSpacePoint handPt = _sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToDepthSpace(position);

Point relativePoint = new Point(
    handPt.X * (1920 / _sensor.DepthFrameSource.FrameDescription.Width), 
    handPt.Y * (1080 / _sensor.DepthFrameSource.FrameDescription.Height) );
cursorX = (int)relativePoint.X;
cursorY = (int)relativePoint.Y;
NativeMethods.SendMouseInput(cursorX, cursorY,
         (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth,
         (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight, leftClick);
```

---

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    public const int InputMouse = 0;

    public const int MouseEventMove = 0x01;
    public const int MouseEventLeftDown = 0x02;
    public const int MouseEventLeftUp = 0x04;
    public const int MouseEventRightDown = 0x08;
    public const int MouseEventRightUp = 0x10;
    public const int MouseEventMiddleDown = 0x0020;
    public const int MouseEventMiddleUp = 0x0040;
    public const int MouseEventAbsolute = 0x8000;
    public const int MouseEventWheelScroll = 0x0800;
    public const int MouseEventWheelHScroll = 0x1000;

    private static bool lastLeftDown = false;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern uint SendInput(uint numInputs, Input[] inputs, int size);

    public static void SendMouseInput(int positionX, int positionY, int maxX, int maxY, bool leftDown)
    {
        if (positionX > int.MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("positionX");
        if (positionY > int.MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("positionY");

        Input[] i = new Input[4];

        // move the mouse to the position specified
        i[0] = new Input();
        i[0].Type = InputMouse;
        i[0].mouseInput.X = (positionX * 65535) / maxX;
        i[0].mouseInput.Y = (positionY * 65535) / maxY;
        i[0].mouseInput.Flags = MouseEventAbsolute | MouseEventMove;

        // determine if we need to send a mouse down or mouse up event
        if (!lastLeftDown && leftDown)
        {
            i[1] = new Input();
            i[1].Type = InputMouse;
            i[1].mouseInput.Flags = MouseEventLeftDown;
            lastLeftDown = true;
        }
        else if (lastLeftDown && !leftDown)
        {
            i[1] = new Input();
            i[1].Type = InputMouse;
            i[1].mouseInput.Flags = MouseEventLeftUp;
            lastLeftDown = false;
        }

        // send it off
        uint result = SendInput(2, i, Marshal.SizeOf(i[0]));
         if (result == 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
}
```

---

Comment: It's not very clear what your problem is. What's the expected behavior ? What do you get instead ?

Comment: I have it working now. Just forgot to use System.WindowsInput namespace. now my mouse cursor moves with the movement of hand. :)

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post it as an answer.